# Access denied when trying to use Mysqlimport Utility (using Root Credentials)

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

We are trying to import large CSV files through Mysqlimport as described in these two articles:
http://chriseiffel.com/everything-linux/how-to-import-a-large-csv-file-to-mysql/
& http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html
But even though I am using root credentials I keep getting the following error:
mysqlimport: Error: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Hopefully some one can help! Thanks in advance.

By the way this is the command we are using:

> mysqlimport --ignore-lines= --fields-terminated-by=, --columns='company, company_addr, city, zipcode, state, phone, fax, email, website, contact_name' --local -u root -p dss_databank /data/brick1/web/web/data_files/test_ssh_insert.csv

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the database password and not the system password of root? Is root really the superuser of the database?

Comment: By the way this is the command we are using: > mysqlimport --ignore-lines= --fields-terminated-by=, --columns='company, company_addr, city, zipcode, state, phone, fax, email, website, contact_name' --local -u root -p dss_databank /data/brick1/web/web/data_files/test_ssh_insert.csv

Comment: Yes it is the superuser... root/password